# jquery mobile - dynamically add toggle switch

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, toggleswitch

Here is my Toggle Switch added dynamically

```
$('#item').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="flip">Status : </label><select class="flip" name="slider" id="flip1" data-role="slider"><option value="false" selected="selected">Off</option><option value="true">On</option></select></div>')
```

My page have the event for change slider

```
$("#flip1").on("slidestart", function(event, ui) {
    alert('test');
});
```

but it does not work!
can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) method, since they are created dynamically

```
$('#item').on("slidestart","#flip1", function(event, ui) {
    alert('test');
});
```